# I purchased ssl from godaddy but domain url redirection have issue

Tags: ssl, opencart

i dont know whats wrong with my settings .i am using opencart 2.3.0.2 .Enabled ssl from settings of my cms.
when i run 
https:sharishari.com
it works fine.
i want when i or any one enter my domain name sharishari.com it should redirect to https:sharishari.com
each time i have to write complete url with https to go on https.
and second thing its view is non responsive and non functional when i write 
sharishari+ctrl Enter .
here is my 
root config file 
i removed www from the domain
and admin
config file
https://codeshare.io/2pAlLV 
i just shared the above part .db part excluded in sharing

Please i will be very thankful if somebody sort out my problem.best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling SSL from your open cart backed, first of all, you will have to update your config files for both catalog and admin. You will have to edit link as "https".

Apart from that, you will have to edit your links provided on header.tpl. Just find and replace all 'http'  to 'https'. You can find header.tpl at catalog/view/theme/themename/common/header.tpl

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in both

```
config.php
admin/config.php
```

to https:

also go to your catalog/view/thene/YOURTHEME/common/header.tpl

And their all of your scripts, css files and so forth to https

And easy way to find them do a `ctrl+f` search on http and you will find the,

If you have any custom code like social media links, you need to change them to https aswell.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5w9DAP this is my header.tpl file ,sorry my english not good.

Comment: what i need to change in this header file.please tell me

Comment: Read what i've written, open you header.tpl file and find everything that starts with "HTTP" and change i to "HTTPS"

Answer (score 0):

OK you need to redirect to HTTPS (opencart does not do this when enabling SSL) and you need to edit your theme header file, see Innervisions comment

Opencart only switches to SSL on checkout, account, login, etc pages.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5w9DAP this is my header.tpl file .if you write in sublime text editor .u will have better understanding of this.